# What exactly does a URL redirect for @ do?

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, cname-record

What exactly does a URL redirect for @ do?

I am familiar with the terminology as seen here. [ [sf](https://serverfault.com/questions/426326/what-is-the-name-for-a-dns-record-starting-with) ]

However, I am trying to understand my DNS records and came across this line:

```
URL Redirect Record | @ | https://www.example.com | Unmasked
```

It appears that is will redirect example.com to https://www.example.com but what about the http and https part?  Does it apply to both?

Will it redirect both http://example.com and https://example.com ?

Comment: DNS has no concept (records) related to HTTP redirections. What you see is specific to one DNS provider so you need to ask him/look at his documentation.

Answer (score 2):

This means your DNS provider has a redirection service they offer. It's not a feature built into DNS; they just have logic to point to a server under their control, where it'll be redirected.

Whether it'll work with HTTPS varies from provider to provider. Most don't; Google Domains is one of the few I've found that does.